# Drilling through the center stud - Can't identify what material is it?

Tags: wood, drill, studs, mount, veneer

I'd need to drill through the center stud above my fireplace to mount a tv. The stud is beside a power outlet.

There is brick veneer in the front and the stud is in the very end but I also see one other material in between. Not sure what that is. Can someone help me identify what that is? And do I need to be aware of any specific requirements while drilling through this?
In the attached image below, I can see that,

- Red line -> Brick Veneer
- Yellow line -> Wood stud
- Blue line -> What is this?

I would like to know what the blue line material is and if a regular drill bit enough for it?

[image]

Comment: What sound does it make when you tap it with a fingernail?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "regular drill bit". Every type of drill is designed for a specific purpose; e.g. a bit designed for drilling holes in masonry will not typically work well for drilling wood, and vise-versa.

Comment: Is this the exterior wall? It looks like concrete block.